# Locale fallbacks in Rails 4 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n, chinese-locale

I am building a Rails 4 site for a client in Singapore, Malaysia, Taiwan and China.

The locale code for a Chinese speaking Malaysian is `zh-MY`.

I would like to keep a base `zh-CN` (Simplified Chinese) set of locale files and for `zh-MY` to fallback to `zh-CN`.

Just having a `zh` is not correct as `zh-TW` (Traditional Chinese) is what Taiwan uses and there are big differences between that and `zh-CN`.

So here's my `config/application.rb` file [as per the Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#localized-views).

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
require "i18n/backend/fallbacks"

module MyAwesomeApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Fallbacks)

    # all translations from config/locales/**/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]

    # The default locale is :en
    config.i18n.default_locale = :en

    # See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#localized-views for a discussion of
    # how language codes fall-back.
    config.i18n.available_locales = [:en, :'zh-CN', :'zh-TW', :'en-SG', :'en-MY', :'zh-MY']
    I18n.fallbacks.map(:'zh-MY' => :'zh-CN')
  end
end
```

But this simply doesn't work.

When I actually set the locale to `:zh-MY` it does not fall back to `:zh-CN` but to `:en`

What am I missing?

**update**:
If I `puts "I18n.fallbacks #{I18n.fallbacks}"` it says `I18n.fallbacks {}`. Clearly `I18n.fallbacks.map` is failing.

**update**
As per the suggestion in the comments I looked at `I18n.fallbacks[:'zh-MY']` in the very next line after I checked `I18n.fallbacks` and it returns `[:"zh-MY", :zh, :"zh-CN", :en]`

**update** 
With a `binding.pry` in my `application controller` I have checked the locale etc and observe this:

```
[1] pry(#<ServicesController>)> I18n.locale
=> :"zh-MY"
[2] pry(#<ServicesController>)> I18n.fallbacks
=> {:en=>[:en], :"zh-MY"=>[:"zh-MY", :zh, :en]}
```

So somewhere between the Rails app starting up and the controller's `set_locale` method being called, `I18n.fallbacks` is being reset to the default.

Comment: You are using unknown locales, not sure if the default backend supports them

Comment: They are all common locale codes and set via `available_locales`

Comment: what do you get from `I18n.fallbacks[:'zh-MY']`?

Comment: well that is weird. `I18n.fallbacks` is `{}` but `I18n.fallbacks[:'zh-MY']` returns `[:"zh-MY", :zh, :"zh-CN", :en]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't ask me why but this works, despite what the official docs say.

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
require "i18n/backend/fallbacks"

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module MyAwesomeApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # all translations from config/locales/**/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]

    # The default locale is :en
    config.i18n.default_locale = :en

    # See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#localized-views for a
    # mostly correct discussion of how language codes fall-back.
    config.i18n.available_locales = [:en, :'zh-CN', :'zh-TW', :'en-SG', :'en-MY', :'zh-MY']
    config.i18n.fallbacks = {:'zh-MY' => :'zh-CN'}
  end
end
```

Removing the `I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Fallbacks)` and setting the fallbacks via `config.i18n.fallbacks = {:'zh-MY' => :'zh-CN'}` rather than `I18n.fallbacks.map(:'zh-MY' => :'zh-CN')` makes it all work perfectly.

And now in my controller, at the same breakpoint as discussed in the 3rd question update:

```
[1] pry(#<ServicesController>)> I18n.fallbacks
=> {:en=>[:en], :"zh-MY"=>[:"zh-MY", :zh, :"zh-CN", :en]}
```

I hope this is helpful to others.